# Are there really walking groups in malls in the US?

Tags: usa, recommendations, walking, group-travel

Tonight I was watching TV and then I saw a walking group of elderly people in a mall. The TV show mentioned that it is a mall walking group.

Since I'm always curious to see new things in the world I have basically two questions:

1) Are there really walking groups in malls in the US?

2) If yes, where should I travel to to optimize my chances to see one?

Comment: Sorry I'm down voting this because I don't think it's a real travel question. It's just a throwaway culture / customs question disguised as a travel question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More likely it was a group that happens to go to a mall to walk, as well as other events.

For example, you can look in a city on [meetup.com](http://www.meetup.com/) for social groups.  I've joined a few in Vancouver.

Several of them will advertise walks - be it around the waterfront, a hike, or quite likely indoors.

Indeed, a [google search](https://www.google.ca/search?q=mall+walk+meetup&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb) will reveal a few - for example, [this Mall Walking meetup with VegasHikers](http://www.meetup.com/VegasHikers/events/75725282/).

Answer (score 5):

There are absolutely groups whose primary purpose is to meet up at malls and walk. Google has this information: here are some examples:

- [Avalon Mall Walkers](http://www.shopavalonmall.com/mall-walkers/)
- [Burlington Ontario](http://www.burlingtonmall.com/mallWalkers.php)
- [List of programs in the Greater Toronto Area](http://www.cardiachealth.ca/templates/content/pages/didyouknow1.html)
- [Article giving some examples](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/expat/expatnews/7071135/Get-fit-in-the-mall.html)